# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor dags in different timezones

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have 2 dags that are in different timezones.
Dag1 runs at 9AM London time and Dag2 9AM HK time.
Dag1 depends on Dag2 and this dependency is created by using an ExternalTaskSensor with an execution_delta of 7 hours (as HK is currently 7 hrs ahead of london and it looks like the ExternalTaskSensor converts everything to UTC behind the scenes)

This is working fine right now but what will happen when the clocks change in London and the time difference between London and HK becomes 8 hours?

Is there a better way to set up the ExternalTaskSensor to account for dags in different TZs?

Comment: You can use `execution_date_fn` to do the adjustments (assuming the time changes aren't random).